Probability of drawing a red ball from a bag given bag state after ball is drawn
I have a bag with only red and blue balls. I take a ball out and hide it. Now there are x red balls and y blue balls in the bag. The bag was created with the following procedure. For each ball, there is a p chance of it being red, and 1-p chance of it being blue. What is the probability the hidden ball is red, expressed using only x, y, and p.

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.

Does this answer your question? Calculating Probability That Drawn Ball Is Red Given The State After It Is Drawn

@Red, good to point out that closely related question, but it doesn't have an accepted answer, or even an answer with positive score.

@GerryMyerson that may be because it was closed not too soon after being asked. Maybe the original question should be re-opened with this as an edit?

Let's look at how we can form the initial configuration: For any ball in the bag, there is a constant probability of p to pick one red ball and q to pick a blue ball; and we know p+q = 1.
When we know there is (x+y+1) balls in the bag, the chance of bag containing (x + 1) red balls and y blue balls is
$$ \binom{x+y+1}{x+1}\cdot p ^{x+1} \cdot q^y $$
And the relative probability of taking a red ball from it is
$$ P(R) = \binom{x+y+1}{x+1}\cdot p ^{x+1} \cdot q^y \cdot \frac{x+1}{x+y+1}
 = \binom{x+y}{x}\cdot p ^{x+1} \cdot q^y  
 = \binom{x+y}{x}\cdot p ^{x} \cdot q^y \cdot p $$
Similarly, the chance of the bag containing x red balls and (y+ 1) blue balls is
$$ \binom{x+y+1}{y+1} \cdot p ^x \cdot q^{y+1} $$
And the relative probability of taking a blue ball from it is
$$ P(B) =  \binom{x+y+1}{y+1} \cdot p ^x \cdot q^{y+1} \cdot \frac{y+1}{x+y+1} 
 = \binom{x+y}{x}\cdot p ^{x} \cdot q^{y+1}  
 = \binom{x+y}{x}\cdot p ^{x} \cdot q^y \cdot q$$
Since the hidden ball can only be red or blue, the probability of hidden ball to be red is:
$$ \frac{P(R)}{P(R) + P(B)}
=  \frac{\binom{x+y}{x}\cdot p ^{x} \cdot q^y \cdot p } {\binom{x+y}{x}\cdot p ^{x} \cdot q^y \cdot (p + q)}
= \frac{p}{p+q}
=  p $$
So the probability of hidden ball to be red is p, regardless of what is observed inside the bag.
